# How can I quickly and easily attach two (or more) piece of paper together with tape?

Tags: paper

I have hundreds of sheets of printed music, all single A4-sized sheets. Many sheets need to be attached (along the long side) to form one long sheet of music made up or two, three or four single A4 sheets of paper. The attachment needs to be durable, so ideally with tape.

Any ideas how this can be done quickly and accurately?

Answer (score 4):

Use [packing tape](http://www.harborfreight.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/image_24106.jpg) it's wide enough to provide you a good grip on the pages, put it on both sides of the sheets, if you want to be able to fold your printed music for easy traveling, then place the sheets half a cm apart before sticking them to the tape.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the joint to be durable, stick tape on both sides especially if you want to fold along the joints. Makes sure you leave a small gap between the pages if you want to fold and make a crease along the joint. Also make sure to use a zig-zag fold(fan fold).

To make the whole sheet durable, use packing tape to tape over the the whole page. This would be similar to laminating the pages.

Comment: Umm so you basically just reworded my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't read your answer completely.

Answer (score 2):

"Just Do It" and "Vinod" have already covered attaching the pages together. You also asked how to align the pages accurately. I suggest blu-tacking a ruler to the surface of the desk or table you are working on. Position it parallel to the edge nearest to you. When you are lining up two pages ready to stick them together, gently push the bottom edge of each page so that they both abut the ruler. That way they will be level with each other.